# Relations inside DTO and php7.4 : how to hydrate?

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I wonder what is the good practices :

Let's say I have 2 entities, ManyToOne. Both are ApiResources, and both have an Output DTO. So Both have a transformer.

```php
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *     output="Dto\Foo"
 * )
 */
class Foo
{
    private int $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bar")
    */
    private Bar $bar;

}
```

Problem is, when I transform the entity Foo into a DTO Foo, I want to hydrate it with a Bar DTO, not a Bar entity. But since I hydrate it with from an entity, I have a Bar entity. Later in the process, the Bar entity is replaced by a Bar DTO, ApiPlateform is working, but my mental problem is : the bar property  type is modified over time (Moreover it can't be Typehinted). Seems dirty to me, isn't it ?

Illustration:

the Transofmer

```php
<?php 

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataTransformer\DataTransformerInterface;

class FooEntityToFooDToTransormer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($object, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        return new FooDto($object);
        // maybe there is a better way to hydrate FooDto, by getting directly a BarDto here ?
    }
}
```

The DTO :

```php
<?php 

namespace Dto;

class Foo
{
    public int $id;

    // problem is I cant typehint here
    public $bar;

    public function __construct(FooEntity $fooEntity)
    {
        $this->id = $fooEntity->getId();
        $this->bar = $fooEntity->getBar(); // <-- return a Bar entity, transformed later by ApiPlatform into a Bar DTO.
    }
}
```

**It there a way or a good practice to proper hydrate a DTO from an entity, especially about relations ?**

Edit :

I actually prefer not Typehint $bar as its normalization (so its transformation) should be handled by ApiPlateform. But then, circular references are not handeled (memory limit) and I don't really know why (probably confusion between object and DTO).

I don't think my FooTransformer should know how to transform Bar, because according to the context I could need one transformer or another, or an IRI... Test all of them with "supportTransformation" and so, for every relation ? And what about circular ?

It's a little mess, my solution for now is to choose to return FooDto (without transform barDto) or to return an IRI, according to the context (which I am absolutly not sure of what I'm doing with it due to the lack of documentation about $context).
Same for BarTransformer.

So every transformer need to choose to actually transform the object without handeling transformation of relations, or return the correspondant IRI. That is the less dirty I found.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two possible solutions here, to extend your DTO's constructor signature by one more argument and adjust your transformer or to do the transformation right inside your DTO's constructor:

```
<?php 

namespace Dto;

class FooDto
{
    public BarDto $bar;

    // first variant

    public function __construct(FooEntity $fooEntity, BarDto $barDto)
    {
        $this->id = $fooEntity->getId();
        $this->bar = $barDto;
    }

    // second
    public function __construct(FooEntity $fooEntity)
    {
        $this->id = $fooEntity->getId();
        $this->bar = new BarDto($fooEntity->getBar());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually prefer not typehint and let ApiPlatform call the proper transformer for Bar, which will chose to return a BarDto or an IRI. See "Edit" part :)